# Why cron jobs didn't be set correctly by Ansible playbook?

Tags: postgresql, cron, ansible, barman

I created this playbook to set crontab:

```
- name: Set PATH to crontab
  cron:
    name: PATH
    env: yes
    user: barman
    job: /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/barman/.local/bin:/var/lib/barman/bin:/usr/pgsql-10/bin/

- name: Automatically run backup for App1
  cron:
    name: "Run Backup for App1"
    minute: "0"
    hour: "3"
    user: barman
    job: "barman cron && barman backup app1"

- name: Automatically run backup for App2
  cron:
    name: "Run Backup for App2"
    minute: "0"
    hour: "4"
    user: barman
    job: "barman cron && barman backup app2"
```

But I only found this under `/etc/cron.d/barman` file:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   user     command
  * *    *   *   *   barman   [ -x /usr/bin/barman ] && /usr/bin/barman -q cron
```

It seems didn't set task correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"I only found this under /etc/cron.d/barman"*

A: Take a look at the user barman's crontab

```
shell> crontab -u barman -l
```

It depends on the OS where these files are stored. For example, Ubuntu stores the files in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` but FreeBSD uses `/var/cron/tabs/`. See parameter [cron_file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cron_module.html#parameters).

Use [cronvar](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cronvar_module.html#cronvar-manage-variables-in-crontabs) to manage variables in crontabs. For example

```
- name: Set PATH to crontab
  cronvar:
    name: PATH
    user: barman
    value: /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/barman/.local/bin:/var/lib/barman/bin:/usr/pgsql-10/bin/
```

, or fix the task cron `Set PATH to crontab`. Quoting from parameter [env](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cron_module.html#parameters):

> "... name and value parameters are the name and the value of environment variable."

```
- name: Set PATH to crontab
  cron:
    name: PATH
    env: yes
    user: barman
    value: /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/barman/.local/bin:/var/lib/barman/bin:/usr/pgsql-10/bin/
```